# JSON.parse crashes with large input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I am currently working on an Excel web Add-in where I am making an ajax call which sometimes returning a very large amount of data. After the data is returned I am iterating through the data and loading values to cells in one sync. If the returned data is big enough it would crash the add-in. For example, I am getting about 80k records. But when I am parsing it to JSON, the app simply crashes. As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/privacy-and-security) link, add-in runs inside an Internet Explorer control in windows environment. I am new to Excel Js API and I am not sure I am doing this portion of my code correctly and I am unable to find any examples of this, any help would be appreciated.

```
 // Get report Data via Report API
        var reportAPI = $("#hiddRptDataUrl").val() + reportID;

        $.getJSON(reportAPI, {
            format: "json"
        })
            .done(function (res) {

// This line crashes the app
                data = JSON.parse(res.ReportDataResult);

                if (typeof data === "undefined") {
                    handleError("No records", "No records found for this report");
                    return;
                }

// if no records then show message via handleError method
                if (data.length > 0) { }
                else {
                    handleError("No records", "No records found for this report");
                    return;
                }

// Here I am iterating through data and creating two data arrays
                   var i = 0, result = [], headers = [];

        $.each(data, function () {
            if (i === 0)
                headers.push([]);

            while (i < data.length) {
                result.push([]);

                for (var key in data[i]) {
                    result[result.length - 1].push(data[i][key]);
                    if (i === 0)
                        headers[0].push(key);
                }

                i++;
            }
    }); //each ends here
        })// done ends here
            .then(function () {

            }).fail(function (jqxhr) {
                if (error.code == "ItemAlreadyExists")
                    handleError("Invalid selection", "Report already exists");
                else
                    handleError("Error while fetching report data", jqxhr.responseText);

            });
```

Comment: Your crash is with `JSON.parse`, not the Excel APIs. The fact that your working on an Excel Add-in is not really connected to the error. I've changed your title and tags to get attention from JavaScript experts.

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to parse too much data at once. Consider batching it instead.

Comment: Thanks.
 I would also like to know if we can change the default browser used to run excel add-in.